# MDL: Fixed header icon misplaced?

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm trying out Material Design Lite to make a nice-looking webpage for a school project. I'm having an issue where the sandwich icon in the header is [off-center for seemingly no reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emXmU.png).

I copied and pasted the exact source from the fixed header example [here](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section) (click the CodePen button to see the exact full source I'm trying) and it doesn't appear the way the examples do.

Is there something I'm missing? It's been a while since I've done HTML/CSS but I don't see why this would be happening. Could it even be a bug? Thanks.

Comment: please can you create fiddle?

Comment: @Jainam https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=5Bi7fcw13r Like this?

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could add a comment to help.  Unfortunately my score is too low. 
I went into the fiddle i believe you created and cut and pasted the info from the code pen.  It looks like it is working.  Please post the code you are using.  Also you mentiono a fixed header but it looks like you are taking the header titled Scrollable Tabs. Correct? 
I would be happy to help, i could imagine there is something in the CSS unless you're not using any of your own style sheets. @Jainam is on the right track by asking if you could set up a fiddle.